# замена одного фото при клике на другие

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, yii2

Есть галерея с главным фото и слайдером под ним(там фото меньше)
подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при клике на фото из слайдера менялось главное фото

Вывожу картинки в магазине след образом:

```
<?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl(), ['alt' => $product->name]) ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="view-product">
    <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl(), ['alt' => $product->name]) ?>
      <!-- <h3>Увеличить</h3> -->
  </div>
  <div id="similar-product" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php $count = count($gallery); $i = 0; foreach ($gallery as $img): ?>
      <?php if($i  % 3 == 0): ?>
      <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) echo ' active' ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= Html::img($img->getUrl('84x84'), ['alt' => '']) ?>
          <?php $i++; if($i % 3 == 0 || $i == $count):?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left item-control" href="#similar-product" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="right item-control" href="#similar-product" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let $lightbox = $('.view-product img');

    $('.carousel-inner img').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let src  =  $(this).attr('src');
        $lightbox.attr('src', src);
        $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');
    })
});
```

Comment: не работает, может ошибка где-то ? у меня после  --- let $lightbox = $('.view-product img);  будто символа в коде не хватает

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: все работает, спасибо тебе большое

Comment: не подскажешь пожалуйста как можно еще сделать чтобы при клике на главную выводилась всплывашка с галереей со всеми фото

Comment: можно попробовать div создать со стилями display:none и по клику на картинку менять значение none на block